# Is it possible to inline git branches in the same repository?

Tags: php, git, xenforo

I have a git structure like this:

- `EventListener/`
- `DataWriter/`
- `Install.php`
- `Uninstall.php`

This is an add-on for XenForo, which runs Zend. I would place these files inside `/library/Vendor/AddOn/`.

Most people package add-ons with a structure like this:

- `upload/`

  - `library/`

    - `Vendor/`

      - `AddOn/`
- `README.md`
- `addon-vendor-addon.xml`

Thy zip this up and instruct people to empty the contents of `upload`/ to their XenForo folder.

Is it possible to have a `master` and `release` branch, where `release` is the zippable contents with an `upload/` folder that contains `master`'s contents?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using some build tool for this.
You can e. g. easily use Gradle to build a ZIP that has any directory structure you want it to have.